# Issue with Browser caching on nodejs using https

Tags: node.js, express, caching, https

I am using Nodejs with ExpressJs, and I try browser caching  by set max-age.
On http, it is working prefect.
But on https, it doesn't cache and always get news.

How could I browser caching on https ?

```
var express = require('express');

var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('https/privateKey.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('https/certificate.crt')
};

var app = express();

var oneDay = 86400000;
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', { maxAge: oneDay }));

http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
https.createServer(options, app).listen(3001);
```

Please refer to attached for more details[image]

[image]

Please help
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome do not cache anything with a self-signed-certificate.

See [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=110649) for  more informations.

Comment: Thank you so much
I have tried on server, and it working perfect

Comment: Please mark this as the right answer so it won't appear in questions list anymore.